# The correct way to check USB power capability

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

Suppose I am creating a USB-C device. (*e.g. LED strip controlled and powered over USB-C*) This device should be able to be plugged into any host USB port and work.

How would I go about limiting the device capabilities based on the power available from the USB port? (*limit the current for the LEDs and/or limit number of them lighting up*) We are communicating over USB and we want to get as much power as possible.

The different standards created over the years each say the maximum a device can draw from a port without negotiation is 100mA or 500mA or 1.8A or something else entirely, and there's so many of them that after two weeks of trying to get to the core of it I'm just lost.

We are ignoring Power Delivery protocol, we only care about 5V.

So here are the core questions:

- Is it possible to (always?) detect host power capabilities?
- Is that possible to do while staying in the USB2.0 communication spec? (*We don't need USB3.0 speeds and complexity just to control an LED strip*)
- Is it possible while being backwards compatible with USB2.0 USB-A adapters?
- Is it possible to correctly detect and get USB3.0 power with only USB2.0 communication?

*The LED strip is just an example to better describe the goal of this question. I'm trying to learn what the USB standard says, recommendatinons on how to implement it are welcome, but not the point of this question.*

Comment: About your first question, I can say that voltages and resistances at/across DM-DP pair tell about the power capabilities of the host (according to USB BC 1.2 spec).

Comment: The resistors in the CC lines of a USB-C port advertise its current capability at 5V. For other voltages you'd need to use the Power Delivery protocol.

Comment: USB protocols do not have any provisions to communicate port power provider capability. This function is delegated to CC pins during primary connect discovery, and then to PowerDelivery protocol (if implemented).

Comment: @RohatKılıç, current USB Type-C standard prohibits BC 1.2 protocol, only PD is allowed.